# How to use setValues in google scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to print a 2D array into a spreadsheet, but I am getting some error and I couldn't find any solution.

Here is my solution:

```
var URL = blabla
var Sheets = [bla,ble,bli]
var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(URL);
var ss3 = doc.getSheetByName(Sheets[2]);
var FinalFacil = [[Matematicas, 1 Medio, Funciones, 6?, 
Facil, A;B;C;D;E, D], [Matematicas, 1 Medio, Funciones, 7?, Facil, 
A;B;C;D;E, E], [Matematicas, 1 Medio, Funciones, 3?, Facil, A;B;C;D;E, A], 
[Matematicas, 1 Medio, Funciones, 4?, Facil, A;B;C;D;E, B]]
ss3.getRange("A1:G4").setValues(FinalFacil);
```

And I am getting the following error: `Cannot find method setValues((class))`

Comment: Everything inside the array should be quoted.`"1 Medio"`

Comment: I think that if ``FinalFacil`` in your script is ``[[Matematicas, 1 Medio, Funciones, 6?, Facil, A;B;C;D;E, D],,,]``, your script cannot be saved because of an error. But in your question, you say that an error of ``Cannot find method setValues((class))`` occurs. So can you provide for replicating your issue?

Comment: @Tanaike, for the variable `FinalFacil`, I pasted the output of my variable as the content of it (thinking that it would be easy to troubleshot). Thing is `FinalFacil` its the result of several filters that I am doing before. So think that `FinalFacil` its just a 2D array.

Comment: @TheMaster Even if I am getting those values strigth out of a spreadsheet?

Comment: @angel  The issue,IMO is - whatever you're doing to the array messes up the array(so much so that it's no more a 2D array) so that it can't be used in setValues. You need to provide [mcve] or exact logs of the array `FinalFacil` just before using it in setValues

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs because is `ss3` is `undefined`. It's `undefined` because the third element of `Sheets` is undefined too.

If your spreadsheet has a sheet named `bli` replace

```
var Sheets = [bla,ble,bli]
```

by

```
var Sheets = [bla,ble,'bli']
```

Comment: If `ss3` is undefined, then Won't ``ss3.getRange()`` in the last line throw the error Cannot find method getRange() in undefined? But the error is Cannot find method setValues((class)). I think the problem is in the array `FinalFacil`

Comment: @TheMaster You are right, but the arrays has the same problem, the strings aren't quote enclosed. Anyway the code isn't complete so it's very likely that has other problems too.